# Remove Shadow on iOS 12.4 Input Elements

Tags: html, ios, iphone, google-chrome, mobile

I've gone through all of the answers, none of which work, in countless questions on SO that all seem to be outdated.

I've tried changing `box-shadow`, `background-clip`, `background-image`, `appearance`, et cetera, of both `input` and `input[type=whatever]`, none of which seems to work in iOS 12.4.

## Safari

[image: ios 12.4 safari input shadow]

## Chrome

[image: ios 12.4 chrome input shadow]

## How can I remove the inset shadows applied to `input` elements in iOS 12.4 for both Chrome and Safari?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `background-clip: padding-box !important` and clearing the cache did the trick.